# Photoshop CS6: color window like color picker

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

How can I set my **Color window** to look/act like the **Color Picker** as does Goro Fujita on his streams?

I know about adding keyboard shortcuts or the interactive color wheel/strip with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd>. I would like to emulate this set up, but haven't found a way.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s Photoshop’s colour panel. It can be opened by choosing `Window` → `Color` (it’s separate to the colour picker that opens when you click the foreground or background colour).

[image: Photoshop color panel]

There’s a few options to control how the color panel looks, under the panel’s fly-out menu. To match the image above, you’ll want `Hue Cube`.

[image: Photoshop color panel hue cube]

Comment: But how'd you make it look like that? ...mine looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rsPx.png)

Comment: @Cai I just added another image that should help. I think you want `Hue Cube`.

Comment: [I don't have any cube options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEtK0.png). Maybe it's new in CC? I still use CS6 (like OP does)

Comment: Yeh, seems it's a CC thing https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2050972

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, I wasn’t sure when that was added.

Comment: I was afraid it was  new in CC, not CS6 :( Too bad then, cause it's real useful. I'll stick to keyboard shortcut which is the next best thing :)